# Need help comparing arrays for lottery simulation

Tags: c#

I probably messed up somewhere here, but this is what I have so far. So how do I compare 6 random generated Winning Numbers for lottery to the User inputed 6 numbers. The instructions says to "display the winning numbers, player’s numbers, and how many numbers matched. For instance, if your winning numbers are 3,5,9,1,4,7 and your player’s numbers are 2,5, 7,1, 9,8, then you have two matches (5 and 1). 5 is on the second position and 1 is on the fourth position in both arrays." Also, I tried to generate the 6 random Winning Numbers using randomInts, but not sure if I was supposed to use "i < list.Length" or something else. Any help appreciated.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //array declarations
        const int SIZE = 6;
        int[] myLottery = new int[SIZE];
        int winning;
        int player;

        //methods call
        FillLottery(myLottery);
        PrintLottery(myLottery);


    }
    //generate 6 random numbers to fill the array
    static void FillLottery(int[] list)
    {
        Random randomInts = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < list.Length; i++)
        {
            list[i] = randomInts.Next(1, 10);
        }
    }
    //print the array
    static void PrintLottery(int[] list)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.Write($"{list[i],2}");
            if ((i + 1) % 10 == 0)
                Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Usually lotteries work by generating unique numbers - as it is you could generate 6 1's for instance. But then again, if each number can only be from 1 to 9 and there's 6 of them, then every single guess will have at least 3 correct numbers!  But then you make it sound like the user has to guess not just the number but what position it occurs in, so can you clarify this?

Comment: Yes, the number and the position have to match.

Comment: _"Any help appreciated"_ -- that's too broad a request. You have not shown _any_ code that appears to try to do what you want. You need to make _some_ attempt. Explain what _specifically_ it is you can't figure out. What does the code do, what do you want instead, and why can't you get it to do that?

Comment: Ok, but is it ok if the lottery generates 6 1's? Anywhere what have you tried so far to read the numbers in from the user, and to then match with the generated random array?

Comment: Sure it is fine to generate 6 1's. To read the numbers in from the user, would I start using a "Static decimal getNumber()" for example? Then use a while{} and return as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest separating this out into 3 separate `for` loops, and an`if/else` statements.

For time saving purposes I have set the max number that the lottery will generate to `1`, although it can be easily changed.   It helps to do each step one by one and slowly build on it rather than doing all at the same time.  I've found this especially true when checking randomly generated numbers against user input.

To keep track of if there is a match between the user's number and the lottery number you can use a `bool[]`.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //create size, and random object
    const int SIZE = 6;
    const int maxNumberInLottery = 1;
    Random rnd = new Random();
    //create int[] for the lot numbers
    int[] lotteryNumbers = new int[SIZE];
    string[] usersNumbers = new string[SIZE];

    //Create a bool[] for each case
    bool[] matches = new bool[SIZE];

    //Create lottery numbers
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        lotteryNumbers[i] = rnd.Next(1, maxNumberInLottery + 1);
    }
    //Read user input
    for(int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++)
    {
        Console.Write("Enter user pick #{0}:", j+1);
        string userInput = Console.ReadLine();
        usersNumbers[j] = userInput;
    }
    //check if matching
    for(int k = 0; k < SIZE; k++)
    {
        Console.Write("You entered: {0}. Lottery generated: {1}", usersNumbers[k], lotteryNumbers[k]);
        Console.WriteLine();
        try
        {

            if (int.Parse(usersNumbers[k]) == lotteryNumbers[k])
            {
                Console.WriteLine("       !MATCH!");
                matches[k] = true;
            }
        }
        catch
        {

        }    
    }
    //check if the bool[] contains any false values at all
    if(!matches.Contains(false))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("WE HAVE A WINNER");
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Output:

```
 Enter user pick#1:1
 Enter user pick#2:21
 Enter user pick#3:1
 Enter user pick#4:2
 Enter user pick#5:1
 Enter user pick#6:3

 You entered: 1. Lottery generated: 1
        !MATCH!
 You entered: 21. Lottery generated: 1
 You entered: 1. Lottery generated: 1
        !MATCH!
 You entered: 2. Lottery generated: 1
 You entered: 1. Lottery generated: 1
        !MATCH!
 You entered: 3. Lottery generated: 1
```

Output 2:

```
 Enter user pick#1:1
 Enter user pick#2:1
 Enter user pick#3:1
 Enter user pick#4:1
 Enter user pick#5:1
 Enter user pick#6:1

 You entered: 1. Lottery generated: 1
        !MATCH!
 You entered: 1. Lottery generated: 1
        !MATCH!
 You entered: 1. Lottery generated: 1
        !MATCH!
 You entered: 1. Lottery generated: 1
        !MATCH!
 You entered: 1. Lottery generated: 1
        !MATCH!
 You entered: 1. Lottery generated: 1
        !MATCH!
WE HAVE A WINNER!
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Quick question. I forgot to state it beforehand, but the random generated 6 numbers is supposed to have an array called "Wining", and the user inputed 6 numbers is to have an array called "Player". Where would I put those?

Comment: @ChrisH  Edited to demonstrate how a bool[] can be used here to represent the matching cases.

Comment: Wow thanks for your help. Just started C# 3 weeks ago and it is really growing on me. Just started learning arrays this week and well I think its pretty fun. Thank you

Comment: @ChrisH no problem, glad to help. I added one more trick in there to checking to see if the bool[] contains any false at all, rather than using a giant if statement.  If this did solve your problem/question please select answer for others to know.

Comment: sorry for asking too many questions but, is "catch{}" similar to using "return;" ? If so, is it possible to use in this case?

Comment: @ChrisH try/catch is used to detect exception errors.  For example, if you typed in letters instead of numbers, the program would normally crash.  Instead of dealing with that I created the try/catch to simply ignore this crash and continue looping.  You can put a return statement in a catch block if desired.  However, in this case it's literally doing nothing except continuing the program when a runtime error occurs from using the comparison operator on a string and int.